# Dual-criminality and conduct approach?

Tags: criminal-law, european-union, extradition, spain

I was reading [this](https://www.spainlawyer.com/legal-guide/extradition-in-spain/) article published by a Spanish lawyer firm, on the topic of extradition from Spain to a requesting country.

I wanted to clarify my understanding of this section, quoted below.

> Under Spanish law, extradition is not possible for citizens located in
> Spain for a conduct that is not a crime in Spain. No one can be
> extradited unless the offense is a crime in both countries and carries
> a prison sentence of at least 1 year.

My understanding: nobody can be extradited from Spain, unless their offence is a crime in both countries. However, the citizens of Spain have an additional protection, that their conduct must also be considered as criminal in Spain.

I assume this means, even though Spain and the requesting country have a law against the corruption of minors, since they are extraditing a Spanish citizen they will also investigate the conduct, and refuse since the conduct is not a crime as Spain has a lower age of consent than the requesting country?

Feel free to provide a better example scenario.

Comment: How is that extra protection for Spanish citizens?  If something is "a crime in both countries" then it is necessarily "a crime in Spain."  If something is not a crime in Spain then it is necessarily not a crime in both countries.  It's just careless writing.  You'd be best served by reading the actual law or at least try to find a summary of it by a legal information service rather than by someone who is trying to sell something.

Comment: @phoog I am sorry. It was because they explained the requirement of it being a crime in both countries, but when speaking about Spanish citizens stated that a conduct approach was taken. This caused me to think too deeply...